# Как повторять загрузку по истечению определенного времени?

Tags: android

Приложение должно периодически подгружать JSON с сервера. Подгрузить JSON, обработать его - не проблема. Не получается зациклить. 
Так, например, в активити пытался сделать так:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_view);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this);

    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    while (true){

        downloader.execute();

        try {

            listOfElements = downloader.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this, 
            listOfElements, 
            R.layout.list, new String[]{
                TITLE,
                TEXT,},
             new int[]{
                    R.id.title,
                    R.id.text}
        );

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Вылетает ошибка IllegalStateExeption: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
Пытался так же вместо TimeUnit использовать Thread.sleep() - тоже вылетает. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

1. Надо каждый раз пересоздавать `AsyncTask` (типа `new Downloader()`) - это более верный способ, чем перезапускать его через `execute`
2. Надо отслеживать завершение таска через `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` выставлением слушателя или хотя бы синхронизированного булевского флажка и запускать новый таск только после окончания предыдущего - заново создавая таск (см. п.1)

Comment: А почему лучше создавать новый AsyncTask?

Comment: AsyncTask не лучше пересоздавать, а нужно пересоздавать.

Comment: А как мне отлавливать моменты когда, допустим мне нужно сделать подгрузку не ожидая, когда истечет определенный промежуток времени, а когда в приложении нажали на кнопку "reload"? Т.е. как сделать так, чтобы таймер шел, но была возможность отлавливать нажатие на кнопку?

Comment: А зачем делать какую-то явную конструкцию для отслеживания окончания загрузки в AsyncTask, если есть метод get(), который просто ждет, пока главный поток что-то получит от AsyncTask. Пока ждет, по идее, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2000); не должен срабатывать

Comment: [Stas0n][1], при такой реализации кнопка "reload" не имеет смысла - потому что в момент нажатия приложение будет либо ждать, либо спать, либо выбросит [ANR][2] ещё до того, как пользователь что-то увидит


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/9148/stas0n
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: А как стоит тогда организовать подгрузку?